# Set cell value using if statement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use an if statement in scripts to set cell values once conditions are met, however its not working and i can't figure out why.

I need to do it using scripts rather than formulas in the sheet itself

```
var mainWSname = "Exposure"

function onEdit(e){

  var activeCell = e.range();
  var r = activeCell.getRow()
  var c = activeCell.getColumn()
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName()

  if(wsName === mainWSname && c === 2 && val === "Match"){

    wsName.getRange(r, 3).setValue("18")
    wsName.getRange(r, 4).setValue("80")

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modification:-

```
var mainWSname = "Exposure"

function onEdit(e){

  var activeCell = e.range;
  var r = activeCell.getRow()
  var c = activeCell.getColumn()
  var val = e.value;
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet()
  if(wsName.getName() === mainWSname && c === 2 && val === "Match"){

    wsName.getRange(r, 3).setValue("18")
    wsName.getRange(r, 4).setValue("80")

  }
}
```

Reference:

[Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thanks but no change, still not working.

Comment: @NColl Try updated modification.